# How to make insert mode mapping count as multiple undos?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, undo-redo

I have the following mappings:

```
nnoremap # /___<CR>ciw
imap # <Esc>:w<CR><Esc>#
```

And the following file that I am editing:

```
foo ___
goo ___
hoo ___
```

The idea is that I start at the beginning of the file, type `#` and I am editing the first `___`, then while still in insert mode, I type `#` again, and I am editing the next `___`, saving between each edit. This works fine, but the problem is that if I make a mistake, and type `u`, it undoes **ALL** the edits and reverts **ALL** of them back to `___` instead of just the most recent change.

How can I do these mappings in a way so that each time I save, it counts as a separate undo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `<c-g>u` in insert mode to break undo sequence and start new change. Like this:

```
imap # <c-g>u<Esc>:w<CR>#
```

(removed the second `<esc>`, as it is not needed.)

See `:help i_CTRL-G_u`

Answer (score 3):

From [`:h undojoin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#%3Aundojoin):

```
One undo command normally undoes a typed command, no matter how many changes
that command makes.  This sequence of undo-able changes forms an undo block.
[...]
To do the opposite, break a change into two undo blocks, in Insert mode use
CTRL-G u.  This is useful if you want an insert command to be undoable in
parts.  E.g., for each sentence.  i_CTRL-G_u
Setting the value of 'undolevels' also breaks undo.  Even when the new value
is equal to the old value.
```

So, you could modify your second mapping to break the undo block (before  the write):

```
imap # <C-G>u<Esc>:w<CR><Esc>#
```

Or the fist mapping to start a new block with input:

```
nnoremap # /___<CR>ciw<c-g>u
```

Comment: Looks like your answer was first, but you were missing the `u` at the end of `<C-G>`. Thank you for the response though!

Comment: Oh, missed that.